# How to edit php.ini in App Engine Flex to enable Google Cloud Debugger for PHP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible, google-cloud-debugger

I am following the steps on this page https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/php?authuser=1 for the App Engine Flex.

At once, the docs asks the following:

```
Install the stackdriver_debugger extension from PECL:

pecl install stackdriver_debugger-alpha

If your php.ini file does not include extension=stackdriver_debugger.so after running this step, add it manually.
```

My app is running on App engine flex. How to access the php.ini on the App Engine Flex?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access or update your files in App Engine Flexible you need to SSH to your App Engine Flex instance and edit the file/s, follow the steps below:

1. First, you need to enable the debug mode in the Cloud Console before you can SSH, you can use `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud app --project [PROJECT-ID] instances enable-debug
```

2. Go to [App Engine > Instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances), click **SSH** in the far right of the row containing the instance you want to access.
3. In the terminal window, to see the container-name and list the containers running in the instance:

```
sudo docker ps
```

4. To enter the conitainer:

```
sudo docker exec -it [CONTAINER-NAME] /bin/bash
```

5. To show your files, execute `ls` then to edit your files execute the ff:

**A.** I'm using **nano** to edit my files. At first there is no package cache in the image, you need to run the ff before you can install the **nano** and use it:

```
apt-get update
```

**B.** Now, install the **nano**

```
apt-get install nano
```

6. Edit your files, example:

```
nano php.ini
```

7. Then save `Ctrl+x`,`Y` and hit `Enter`. When you are finished debugging or updating the file/s, enter `exit` to exit the container, then `exit` again to exit the SSH session.
8. Lastly, disable debugging for your instance to allow it to resume normal operation.

```
gcloud app --project [PROJECT-ID] instances disable-debug
```